# sudo chgrp and sudo chmod will be reset after reboot

Tags: permissions, 22.04, chmod

quick summary:
I met some problem during my work on OrangePi 5 plus develop board, the operation like chgrp and chmod will be reset as default after reboot. I installed official Ubuntu 22.04 image which provided on OrangePi website.

detailed information:
I have to interact with `gpio` using python, which is owned by `root` and in group `root`, so I need to require privileges for my local user. Then I use `sudo chmod 755` to change the mode of some interactive file in `/sys/class/gpio`. The issue is that after changing the mode, I still can not run it without `sudo` or `root` privileges. even more, after `reboot`, the mode of interactive port has been reset as default.

what I have tried:
I also tried to use `sudo chgrp` to change the group of those interactive ports to a certain group, in which my user has permissions. I even add my local user to `root` group, but I still not have permissions to interact with port without `sudo` and password. and the result of `chgrp` will also be reset after reboot. I have run out of solutions, thus I come here for an answer. Thanks for your attention!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For official [Ubuntu](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/rpi.gpio-common) you might be able to use (it is not supported on all machines)

```
sudo apt install rpi.gpio-common
```

For the udev method see `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-com.rules:`

```
SUBSYSTEM=="gpio*", ACTION=="add", PROGRAM="/bin/sh -c 'chgrp -R gpio /sys/${DEVPATH} && chmod -R g+w /sys/${DEVPATH}'"
```

Comment: I also tried to add udev rules written in OPi.GPIO document, but it does't work. The rules are defined like below:
SUBSYSTEM==”gpio”, KERNEL==”gpiochip*”, ACTION==”add”, PROGRAM=”/bin/sh -c ‘chown root:gpio /sys/class/gpio/export /sys/class/gpio/unexport ; chmod 220 /sys/class/gpio/export /sys/class/gpio/unexport’” SUBSYSTEM==”gpio”, KERNEL==”gpio*”, ACTION==”add”, PROGRAM=”/bin/sh -c ‘chown root:gpio /sys%p/active_low /sys%p/direction /sys%p/edge /sys%p/value ; chmod 660 /sys%p/active_low /sys%p/direction /sys%p/edge /sys%p/value’”

Comment: I'm not sure if it is the sd card write protection issue. I use a micro sd card to install the ubuntu image, will the write protection of sd card cause the reset of chgrp and chmod?